# pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField dont keep appearance settings

Tags: itext, acrofields

I use iTextSharp 5.5.13 to create pdf file with text AcroFields and in a second step edit the pdf filling the AcroFields with some values.

For some fields i have to set a character spacing, so i use `CreateAppearance` method. this is the code:

```
var appearance = writer.DirectContent.CreateAppearance(box.Width, box.Height);
appearance.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, obj.FontSize);
appearance.SetColorFill(new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(obj.Color));
appearance.SetCharacterSpacing(obj.CharSpacing);
formField.DefaultAppearanceString = appearance;
formField.SetAppearance(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, appearance);

writer.AddAnnotation(formField);
```

this code produce expected pdf result with fine character spacing in editable fields.

The problem is when i edit the pdf to fill AcroFields with:

```
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(fieldName, fieldValue);
```

the resulting flattened pdf does not mantain the appearence character spacing...

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For generating text field appearances iText 5.x only uses the font, font size, and color information from the **DA** default appearance string (and the color information only if set using the **g**, **rg**, or **k** instructions), cf. the `AcroFields` method `SplitDAelements` which is used to extract information from the **DA** string.

So the iText 5.x appearance generation is quite limited and in particular does not support character spacing.

A possible work-around is for you to explicitly create all the appearances in your own code.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, how can i create the appearances in my own code? can you provide me a little example? do you know if this feature is supported in iText 7?

Comment: @Claudio Essentially you already *do* create an appearance in your own code, you merely do so before setting the `formField` value. All you have to do is to *first* set that value and *thereafter* use `formField.SetAppearance` with an appearance that includes the values layout'ed as you desire.